# progressbar while loading AlerDialogBox

Tags: android

i have a button that display a AlertDialog in witch i do some calculations and it takes sometime, i would like to show a progressbar while doing the calculations.
this is what i have so far but it is not working like i want.
the dialog show but despair before the AlertDialog finished doing the calculations

this the code

```
public void OnClick(View v) {

    try {

        new DownloadingProgressTask().execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
    }

}
    private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Calculations.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflatedview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calculationhelp, null);

            final TextView result = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewresult);
            titleAlerDialog = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            messageAlerDialog = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewMsg);

            separated = help.toString().split("#");

            Resources r = getResources();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {

                        tableResults = r.getStringArray(R.array.Calculo1Results1);
                        result.setText(r.getString(R.string.calculo1results1));
            }

            titleAlerDialog.setText(separated[0]);

            messageAlerDialog.setText(separated[1].toString());


            /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(2, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < tableResults.length; i++) {
                /* Create a new row to be added. */
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(Calculations.this);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                /* Create a cell1 to be the row-content. */
                TextView cell1 = new TextView(Calculations.this);
                TextView cell2 = new TextView(Calculations.this);
                TextView cell3 = new TextView(Calculations.this);

                String[] cells = tableResults[i].toString().split("@");

                cell1.setWidth(130);
                cell1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                        | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell1.setText(cells[0].toString());
                cell1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                cell2.setWidth(130);
                cell2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                        | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell2.setText(cells[1].toString());
                cell2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                cell3.setWidth(130);
                cell3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                        | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell3.setText(cells[2].toString());
                cell3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                /* Add cell1 to row. */
                tr.addView(cell1);
                tr.addView(cell2);
                tr.addView(cell3);

                /* Add row to TableLayout. */
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            }
            //dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

if (dialog.isShowing()) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}

if (success) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calculations.this);
    dialog1.setNegativeButton("Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    dialog1.setView(inflatedview);
    final AlertDialog alert = dialog1.create();
    alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    alert.show();



    ((Button) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button2))
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_red);
    ((Button) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button2))
            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


} else {
    Toast.makeText(Calculations.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
}

}
```

any help would be appreciated
best regards
HP

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following. I've added a constructor to your AsyncTask that accepts a Context, and used it throughout to create your views etc. I've also moved the creation of the second alert dialog into doInBackground(), and left only the code that displays it in onPostExecute(). It should speed things up.

```
public void OnClick(View v) {

    try {

        new DownloadingProgressTask(getBaseContext()).execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
    }

}

private class DownloadingProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    Context mContext;

    public DownloadingProgressTask(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

    final AlertDialog alert;
    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflatedview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calculationhelp, null);

            final TextView result = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewresult);
            titleAlerDialog = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            messageAlerDialog = (TextView) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.textViewMsg);

            separated = help.toString().split("#");

            Resources r = getResources();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {

                tableResults = r.getStringArray(R.array.Calculo1Results1);
                result.setText(r.getString(R.string.calculo1results1));
            }

            titleAlerDialog.setText(separated[0]);

            messageAlerDialog.setText(separated[1].toString());

            /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) inflatedview.findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
            tl.setColumnStretchable(2, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < tableResults.length; i++) {
                /* Create a new row to be added. */
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                /* Create a cell1 to be the row-content. */
                TextView cell1 = new TextView(mContext);
                TextView cell2 = new TextView(mContext);
                TextView cell3 = new TextView(mContext);

                String[] cells = tableResults[i].toString().split("@");

                cell1.setWidth(130);
                cell1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell1.setText(cells[0].toString());
                cell1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                cell2.setWidth(130);
                cell2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell2.setText(cells[1].toString());
                cell2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                cell3.setWidth(130);
                cell3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                cell3.setText(cells[2].toString());
                cell3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.celda_cuerpo);
                cell3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                /* Add cell1 to row. */
                tr.addView(cell1);
                tr.addView(cell2);
                tr.addView(cell3);

                /* Add row to TableLayout. */
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                dialog1.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

                dialog1.setView(inflatedview);
                alert = dialog1.create();
                alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            }
            // dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (success) {
            alert.show();

            ((Button) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button2)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_red);
            ((Button) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button2)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: after the code change.it does behaved like it suppose to, but the sniper just freezes until the calculations are done.

Comment: after the change eclipse show error The constructor Calculations.DownloadingProgressTask(Context) is never used locally

Comment: My mistake. Remove the final part, just leave `AlertDialog alert;`

Comment: after the change eclipse show warning  The constructor Calculations.DownloadingProgressTask(Context) is never used locally

Comment: side note AlertDialog alert; is declare at class level

Comment: That's the constructor for the AsyncTask, and you should call it as I showed in the onClick. If it still gives the warning, ignore it.

Comment: for some reason nothing happen

Comment: Nothing happened when you did what?

Comment: public DownloadingProgressTask(Context c) is never reach

Comment: How to you create the AsyncTask?

Comment: i do not understand your question. i just grab the code from an example

Comment: i really appreciated your help i have to go to work have a nice day.